# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp_var' referenced before assignmen

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

my function is that

```
def func_1(df):
for count1, i in enumerate(df["col1"]):
    if df.at[count1, "col3"] == 1 and df.at[count1, "col4"] > 0:
        tot_fun= df.at[count1, "col4"]
        for count2, j in enumerate(df["col2"]):
            if i == j:
                tot_fun= tot_fun- df.at[count2, "col4"]

                if df.at[count2, "col4"] == 0:
                    temp_var= count2
            df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun
return (df)
```

i want to set the value  in the last line  `df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun`
after i done the second loop in any iteration.
So I saved the position of the variable which I want to change in "temp_var" but i get this error when i call the function

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp_var' referenced before assignment**

Anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: If `df.at[count2, "col4"] == 0:` hasn't been `True` before, `temp_var` has never been defined.

Comment: i want to save the location where  "df.at[count2, "col4"] == 0:" is True but because its can be In the middle of the iteration so i like to save it befor i set the value on the df

Comment: If the condition fails in 1st "if" loop, `df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun` here, temp_var will be unknown to the compiler, initialize temp_var before the loop,

Comment: @EMKAY You have to use `backticks` to do code formatting :)

Comment: So how can I place at the end of each iteration the required value in the required place?

Comment: Initialise temp_var before every iteration or put this (`df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun`) inside your second if-condition.

Comment: if i do that the tot_fun can change after i set it on "df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun" because the second loop do not done yet

Comment: Would you like to provide an input sample, as well as expected output? There might be a more effective way to do what you're trying to do that iterate over the dataframe.

Comment: Please [edit] to fix the broken indentation. People who want to help you should not have to guess whether the indentation is wrong or misleading. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to indent it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Reaches line `df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun` before `temp_var= count2`
maybe insert `df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun` into the if statement

Answer (score 0):

i add `elif` and set `temp_var=1` befor the second loop,
now its work.  Thank you all

```
def func_1(df):
for count1, i in enumerate(df["col1"]):
    if df.at[count1, "col3"] == 1 and df.at[count1, "col4"] > 0:
      tot_fun= df.at[count1, "col4"]
      temp_var= 1
      for count2, j in enumerate(df["col2"]):
          if i == j and df.at[count2,"col4"]>0:
              tot_fun= tot_fun- df.at[count2, "col4"]
          elif i == j and df.at[count2,"col4"]==0 :
              temp_var= count2
                 
       df.at[temp_var, "col4"] = tot_fun
```

return (df)